# Can't scale and move components in IntelliJ

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I can't scale and move components in IntelliJ with its GridLayout. The problem is when I move/scale components they don't move to the exact place.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMxhx.png) (But I think you'd better check the vid out)

I uploaded a video on youtube

Here it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=9&v=X6CF7TJ7GJg (sorry for a non-english speech)

Comment: this escalates quickly... now we have to deal not with code pictures, but with code videos...

Comment: I had no idea how to explain it clearly with no visual support, sorry

Comment: I have to say - this is the first time I have ever seen someone post a video regarding their issue

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how [Java Swing Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) work. Most layout managers do not allow you to place the components where you want (there is so called [Null-layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), but it's not supported by IntelliJ IDEA).

You normally use splits, spacers and constraints to define where the components will appear and how they will resize when the form is resized.